# Multiple Patronuses

Tags: harry-potter, patronus-charm

In Harry Potter, we do not see or hear about anyone conjuring more than one Patronus (that I remember), except for Professor McGonagall:

> 'We must alert the other Heads of House. You’d better put that Cloak back on.’
>
> She marched towards the door, and as she did so she raised her wand. From the tip burst **three silver cats** with spectacle markings around their eyes. The **Patronuses** ran sleekly ahead, filling the spiral staircase with silvery lights, as Professor McGonagall, Harry and Luna hurried back down.
>
> *-Deathly Hallows - page 480 - Bloomsbury - chapter 30, The Sacking of Severus Snape*

**How is it that she was able to produce more than one?**

We know that it takes a seeming amount of energy to produce one: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/8528/21267

Also her Patronuses (Patronii?) were small; could this have helped?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Patronuses were also used for sending messages - especially between order members. See [Messenger Spells](http://www.hp-lexicon.org/magic/spells/spells_m.html#messenger_spell)

In your quote - McGonagall states that she wants to alert the other heads of houses - i.e 3 different individuals - about the events that transpired. That was how she was able to produce more than one since the intended recipients were more than one.

Regarding the amount of energy required - I don't believe that a happy memory is required to produce a messenger spell - since no incantation is required. The patronus is only an embodiment of the message - to identify the sender.

Edit: Found the right archived link https://web.archive.org/web/20110806214330/http://www.jkrowling.com/textonly/en/faq_view.cfm?id=99